# Concatenate within a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use a variable inside jquery id selector?

```
function more_comments(x){
    var datalist = "#s" + x;

    $('datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
}
```

I've tried this

```
var datalist = "s" + x;
$('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
```

and this.

```
$('#s' + x li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
```

If i manually write

```
$('#s50 li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
```

and click on the tag with an id == s50, it works perfectly. I searched for the correct syntax and can't find it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: $(\`#s${x} li:hidden\`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this?

```
var x = 's50';
$('#' + x + ' li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
```

Comment: @baao sorry my bad :) thnx

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @John glad it works for you, by the way you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate a variable and a string, the variable needs to be outside of any `'` or `"`:

```
function more_comments(x){
    var datalist = "#s" + x;
    $(datalist + ' li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
}
```

Using a template string (not supported by IE), you could use

```
$(`#s${x} li:hidden`).slice(0, 2).show();
```

And to avoid the variable creation beforehand

```
function more_comments(x){
    $('#s' + x + ' li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
}
```